# Trouble following canonical quantization of massive scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization

For the massive scalar field, the mode expansion is given by

$$\hat{\phi}(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(2E_\mathbf{p})^{1/2}} (\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + \hat{a}_\mathbf{p}^\dagger e^{i\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}})$$

We know that the Hamiltonian is given by the volume integral of the Hamiltonian density for the massive scalar field

$$\hat{H} = \int d^3 x \, \,  \frac{1}{2} \left\{ [\partial_0 \hat{\phi}(x)]^2 + [\nabla \hat{\phi}(x)]^2 + m^2[\hat{\phi}(x)]^2 \right\}$$

And that since we know that the momentum density is

$$\hat{\Pi}_\mu (x) = \partial_\mu \hat{\phi}(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}(2E_\mathbf{p})^{1/2}} (-ip_\mu) (\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}^\dagger_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}})$$

We can find the temporal and spatial components of the four-momentum density. They come out to be the following (the metric signature being used is (+, -, -, -))

$$\partial_0 \hat{\phi}(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}(2E_\mathbf{p})^{1/2}}(-i E_\mathbf{p}) (\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}^\dagger_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}})$$

$$\nabla \hat{\phi}(x)  = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}(2E_\mathbf{p})^{1/2}}(i\mathbf{p}) (\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}^\dagger_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}})$$

From here, all I have to do is plug these into the volume integral of the Hamiltonian density I've got up above and simplify it. But this is where I'm having problems and don't really understanding what's going on. The next thing they write in my book (Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur) is that

$$\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^3 x \,\, d^3 p\,\, d^3 q}{(2\pi)^3 (2E_\mathbf{p})^{1/2}(2E_\mathbf{q})^{1/2}}  [(-E_\mathbf{p} E_\mathbf{q} - \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{q}) [\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}_\mathbf{p}^\dagger e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}] $$

$$ \times \,\,\, [\hat{a}_\mathbf{q} e^{-i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}_\mathbf{q}^\dagger e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x}}] + m^2[\hat{a}_\mathbf{p} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}_\mathbf{p}^\dagger e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}][\hat{a}_\mathbf{q} e^{-i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x}} - \hat{a}_\mathbf{q}^\dagger e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x}}]$$

Question:  Where did the $d^3 q$ come from? How did they go from what we had just covered to this integral?

The relevant page of the book - QFT For the Gifted Amateur - is 103. Thanks for any help. If I can get past this step, I'll finally have a quantum field!

Comment: The fields are given by integrals over momenta. You have two fields, and so you have two integrals: $\phi^2\sim\int\ d^3p\ d^2q$, where $q$ is a new momentum integration variable. You don't want to use $p$ twice, for they are two different dummy variables.

Comment: Further to the comments of @AccidentalFourierTransform, the integration over $x$ usually affords you a $\delta(p-q)$. As such, the end result only involves a single $p$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks